# Setting relative path for fopen?

Tags: php

How am I supposed to set relative paths for fopen() method in PHP?

When I do simple fopen('asd.txt') it works. But when I do fopen('x/a.txt') it dies:

```
 case 'programme=a-level&division=firm-wide':
   $fp = fopen("a-level/firm-wide.html", 'a') or die("Unable to open file!");
   break;
 case 'programme=a-level&division=sales-and-trading':

   $fp = fopen("a-level/sales-and-trading.html", 'a') or die("Unable to open 
file!");
   break;

 case 'programme=a-level&division=investment-banking':
   $fp = fopen("a-level/investment-banking.html", 'a') or die("Unable to open file!");
   break;
```

Comment: Does the folder `x` exist already?

Comment: Yes it does exist.

Comment: If `x` exists, are you sure that its permissions allow you to read the content?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.